# Prove that maximum likelihood estimators for Gaussian distribution are a global maximum

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I'm studying on Casella-Berger, I'm at page 322 in which it explain how to find MLE for a Gaussian distribution with parameter $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, both unknown.
It finds MLE, and up to this point it is all clear, and they are $\hat{\mu} = \bar{x}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$.

Now, it says it is difficult to prove analitically that these are global maxima indeed, and it uses this fact:

If $\theta \ne \bar{x}$ then $\sum (x_i-\theta)^2 > \sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2$.

It doesn't give any explaination for that. Is there something obvious I don't see?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: given this, how does it proves that they are maxima?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a sum-of-squares argument to see this.

$$\sum_i (x_i-\theta)^2 = \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x}+\bar{x}-\theta)^2 = \sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2+n(\bar{x}-\theta)^2+\\\color{red}{2(\bar{x}-\theta)\sum_i(x_i-\bar{x})}$$

Now, $\bar{x}$ is defined so that the cross term becomes zero since $\sum_i x_i = \sum_i \bar{x}$.

We are therefore left with:

$$\sum_i (x_i - \theta)^2 = \sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2+n(\bar{x}-\theta)^2$$

This is the [variance/bias decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Bias.E2.80.93variance_decomposition_of_squared_error) of the squared-error associated with estimator $\theta$. Since both terms on the RHS are positive and only the bias term depends on $\theta$, we have:

$$\sum_i (x_i - \theta)^2 > \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$\theta\mapsto \sum (x_i-\theta)^2$ is a quadratic function in $\theta$ that opens upwards. It has a unique minimum where its derivative is $0$, that is to say when $2\sum (x_i-\theta)=0$ ie $\theta = \hat x$.